# looping a pyqt window

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pyqt

I am looking to use a 'while' loop to open the same PyQT window after it has been closed, but for some reason the window freezes and stops responding when it tries to loop. I have tried all I know, but nothing seems to fix it. Any suggestions?

```
    while active=="y":
        formclass, baseclass = uic.loadUiType("mainwindow.ui")
        class MyForm(baseclass, formclass):
           def __init__(self, parent=None):
              QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
              self.setupUi(self)
              self.steps_to_battle = random.randint(1,25)
              self.runclicks=0
              self.bikeclicks=0
              self.steps = 0
              self.actionFeed.triggered.connect(self.feed_Click)
              self.actionWalk.triggered.connect(self.walk_Click)
              self.actionPlay.triggered.connect(self.play_Click)
              self.actionDoctor.triggered.connect(self.doctor_Click)
              self.actionRun.triggered.connect(self.run_Click)
              self.actionBike.triggered.connect(self.bike_Click)
              self.doctor = False
              self.walking = False
              self.playing = False
              self.eating = False
              self.sleeping = False
              self.time_cycle = 0
              self.hunger = 0
              self.happiness  = 8
              self.health = 8
              self.forceAwake = False
              self.doctorImages =["walk_forward1.png","walk_forward2.png","walk_forward3.png","walk_forward2.png"]
              self.eatImages = ["walk_backward1.png", "walk_backward2.png", "walk_backward3.png", "walk_backward2.png"]
              self.walkImages = ["walk_left1.png", "walk_left2.png", "walk_left3.png", "walk_left2.png"]
              self.playImages = ["walk_right1.png", "walk_right2.png", "walk_right3.png", "walk_right2.png"]
              self.nothingImages  = ["stand_forward.png", "stand_left.png", "stand_backward.png", "stand_right.png"]
              self.imageList = self.nothingImages
              self.imageIndex = 0
              self.myTimer1 = QtCore.QTimer(self)
              self.myTimer1.start(500)
              self.myTimer1.timeout.connect(self.animation_timer)
              self.myTimer2 = QtCore.QTimer(self)
              self.myTimer2.start(5000)
              filehandle = True
              try:
                  file = open("savedata_vp.pkl", "r")
              except:
                  filehandle = False
              if filehandle:
                  save_list = pickle.load(file)
                  file.close()
              else:
                  save_list = [8, 8, 0, datetime.datetime.now(), 0]
              self.happiness = save_list[0]
              self.health    = save_list[1]
              self.hunger    = save_list[2]
              timestamp_then = save_list[3]
              self.time_cycle = save_list[4]
              difference = datetime.datetime.now() - timestamp_then
              ticks = difference.seconds / 50
              for i in range(0, ticks):
                  self.time_cycle += 1
              self.imageList = self.nothingImages
          def run_Click(self):
              self.runclicks=self.runclicks+1
              if self.runclicks==1:
                  self.bikeclicks=0
                  self.doctorImages = ["run_forward1.png","run_forward2.png","run_forward3.png","run_forward2.png"]
                  self.eatImages = ["run_backward1.png", "run_backward2.png", "run_backward3.png", "run_backward2.png"]
                  self.walkImages = ["run_left1.png", "run_left2.png", "run_left3.png", "run_left2.png"]
                  self.playImages = ["run_right1.png", "run_right2.png", "run_right3.png", "run_right2.png"]
              else:
                  self.runclicks=0
                  self.doctorImages = ["walk_forward1.png","walk_forward2.png","walk_forward3.png","walk_forward2.png"]
                  self.eatImages = ["walk_backward1.png", "walk_backward2.png", "walk_backward3.png", "walk_backward2.png"]
                  self.walkImages = ["walk_left1.png", "walk_left2.png", "walk_left3.png", "walk_left2.png"]
                  self.playImages = ["walk_right1.png", "walk_right2.png", "walk_right3.png", "walk_right2.png"]
          def bike_Click(self):
              self.bikeclicks=self.bikeclicks+1
              if self.bikeclicks==1:
                  self.runclicks=0
                  self.doctorImages = ["bike_forward1.png","bike_forward2.png","bike_forward3.png","bike_forward2.png"]
                  self.eatImages = ["bike_backward1.png", "bike_backward2.png", "bike_backward3.png", "bike_backward2.png"]
                  self.walkImages = ["bike_left1.png", "bike_left2.png", "bike_left3.png", "bike_left2.png"]
                  self.playImages = ["bike_right1.png", "bike_right2.png", "bike_right3.png", "bike_right2.png"]
                  self.nothingImages  = ["bike_stop_forward.png", "bike_stop_left.png", "bike_stop_backward.png", "bike_stop_right.png"]
                  self.imageList = self.nothingImages
                  self.imageIndex = 0
              else:
                  self.bikeclicks=0
                  self.doctorImages = ["walk_forward1.png","walk_forward2.png","walk_forward3.png","walk_forward2.png"]
                  self.eatImages = ["walk_backward1.png", "walk_backward2.png", "walk_backward3.png", "walk_backward2.png"]
                  self.walkImages = ["walk_left1.png", "walk_left2.png", "walk_left3.png", "walk_left2.png"]
                  self.playImages = ["walk_right1.png", "walk_right2.png", "walk_right3.png", "walk_right2.png"]
                  self.nothingImages  = ["stand_forward.png", "stand_left.png", "stand_backward.png", "stand_right.png"]
          def doctor_Click(self):
              self.imageList = self.doctorImages
              self.doctor = True
              self.walking = False
              self.eating = False
              self.playing = False
          def feed_Click(self):
              self.imageList = self.eatImages
              self.eating = True
              self.walking = False
              self.playing = False
              self.doctor = False
          def play_Click(self):
              self.imageList = self.playImages
              self.playing = True
              self.walking = False
              self.eating = False
              self.doctor = False
          def walk_Click(self):
              self.imageList = self.walkImages
              self.walking = True
              self.eating = False
              self.playing = False
              self.doctor = False
          def stop_Click(self):
              self.imageList = self.nothingImages
              self.walking = False
              self.eating = False
              self.playing = False
          def animation_timer(self):
              self.imageIndex += 1
              if self.imageIndex >= len(self.imageList):
                  self.imageIndex = 0
              icon = QtGui.QIcon()
              current_image = self.imageList[self.imageIndex]
              if self.doctor==True or self.eating==True or self.playing==True or self.walking==True:
                  if self.runclicks==0 and self.bikeclicks==0:
                       self.steps=self.steps+0.5
                  elif self.runclicks==1 and self.bikeclicks==0:
                       self.steps=self.steps+1
                  elif self.runclicks==0 and self.bikeclicks==1:
                       self.steps=self.steps+1.5
              if self.steps>=self.steps_to_battle:
                  easygui.msgbox("A wild Pokemon appeared!")
                  self.close()
              icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(current_image),
                             QtGui.QIcon.Disabled, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
              self.petPic.setIcon(icon)
          def closeEvent(self, event):
              file = open("savedata_vp.pkl", "w")
              save_list = [self.happiness, self.health, self.hunger, datetime.datetime.now(), self.time_cycle]
              pickle.dump(save_list, file)
              event.accept()
          def menuExit_selected(self):
              self.close()
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      myapp = MyForm()
      myapp.show()
      app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! May I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People are more likely to help if they don't have to trawl through reams of code.

Comment: I think it's easy. closeEvent() is called when you close the windows. Then in closeEvent() you just call the another method again i.e. self.show(). So whenever window is closed, it again gets opened

Comment: That seems to be working. Thanks for the help!